# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for...Custum jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery

I've searched, and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966487/jquery-ui-autocomplete-json-gives-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-ope), [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617367/cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-id-in), and [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183183/cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-in-undefined), and while they are close nothing seems to match my problem.

I'm trying to spin [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555995/jquery-each-letter-in-div-element-random-colour-from-array-on-hover#12556124) into a plugin, and this isn't the [first time I got stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851982/listener-in-custom-jquery-plugin-not-firing-using-a-variable-for-on-event).

**The Problem**

I'm trying to create a jQuery Plugin that wraps each letter with a span, and then styles it with random colors and font sizes.  The plugin should work on hover, or click.  When the page first loads, there are no errors.  On hover, or click, the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for..." appears.

**The HTML**

```
<div id="firstBox">This box works on hover!</div>
<div id="secondBox">This box works on click!</div>
<div id="thirdBox">This box has custom settings!</div>
```

**The jQuery**

```
;(function ($) {
  $.fn.randomLetterStyles = function( options ) {

    var settings = $.extend({
      colors: ["#ddd", "#333", "#999", "#bbb"],
      sizes:["12"],
      type:"hover",
      defaultColor: "#999",
      defaultSize: "12"
    }, options );

    if(settings.type == "hover") {
      $(this).hover(function(){      
          wrapLetters(this);
          $('.random-styles', this).css('color', randomColor());
          $('.random-styles', this).css('font-size', randomSize());
      }, function(){
          $('.random-styles', this).css({'color':settings.defaultColor, 'font-size':settings.defaultSize});     
      }); 
    }
    else if(settings.type == "click") {
      $(this).on("click", function() {
          wrapLetters(this);
          $('.random-styles', this).css('color', randomColor());
          $('.random-styles', this).css('font-size', randomSize());
      });
    }
    else {
      return "Invalid Type";
    }
  };    


  //Recursive function by Logan Smyth
  // Wrap every letter in a <span> with .random-color class.
  function wrapLetters(el){
    if ($(el).hasClass('random-styles')) return;

    // Go through children, need to make it an array because we modify
    // childNodes inside the loop and things get confused by that.
    $.each($.makeArray(el.childNodes), function(i, node){
      // Recursively wrap things that aren't text.
      if (node.nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE) return wrapLetters(node);

      // Create new spans for every letter.
      $.each(node.data, function(j, letter){
        var span = $('<span class="random-styles">').text(letter);
        node.parentElement.insertBefore(span[0], node);
      });

      // Remove old non-wrapped text.
      node.parentElement.removeChild(node);
    });
  }

  function randomColor() {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * settings.colors.length);
    return settings.colors[index];
  }

  function randomSize() {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * settings.sizes.length);
    return settings.sizes[index];
  }
} ( jQuery )); 

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#firstBox").randomLetterStyles();
  $("#secondBox").randomLetterStyles({type:"click"});
  $("#thirdBox").randomLetterStyles(); 
});
```

If it helps, I have [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/U78RV/) to play with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the following section:

```
$.each(node.data, function(j, letter){
  var span = $('<span class="random-styles">').text(letter);
  node.parentElement.insertBefore(span[0], node)
});
```

`node.data` returns a string representation of the text in the `<span>`. You need to convert this to a char array, as $.each only works for arrays. It cannot iterate over each character in a string natively.

```
var d = node.data.split(''); // converts string to char array
$.each(d, function (j, letter) {
    var span = $('<span class="random-styles">').text(letter);
    node.parentElement.insertBefore(span[0], node);
});
```

There is also a problem with your variable scope in regards to `settings`. The variable needs to be global in the plugin, not just in the init function.

[Check out this JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/8pU6L/)